Iterate over fields of a struct and take into account variable's name
Let's say I have this kind of struct:
#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct{
    pub foo: f64,
    pub foo_rate: f64,
    pub bar: f64,
    pub bar_rate: f64,
    ...etc
}

Is there a way to iterate over each field and add them to a total, but only do so if it is not a rate? (also there is not always a rate)?
like (pseudo code):
let my_struct = MyStruct { };
let total = my_struct.iter().map( |n| if variable name does not contain "rate" then sum += n) // of course not this line of code.


You can do this only using procedural macro. Rust does not have runtime reflection, so you only can generate such code during compilation.

Ok thank you Aleksander, what about summing up the items? I just created a sub structure that does not contain the rates :)

Once you are writing proc macro, you can do anything. You can for example generate a method where you manually add relevant fields.

Why do you need a proc macro for something that simple? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8d5ce7e0d22b67667092d704bb740e1

@ChayimFriedman it is to sum elements within the struct without stating their variable name, not the objects belonging to the vec

For people quick to lock questions, I have already read the related answer which is 8 years old and the answer is "No". But I can't believe that Rust has not been through a lot of changes in the past 8 years.

"Without stating their name" is an arbitrary requirement. Give up on it and your life will be much easier. Unless you have dozens of such fields, but in this case, you really should redesign your structs...

Rust has not changed (with respect to this) because there is nothing to change. The current situation is excellent. Structs are heterogenous collections, and as such, there is no meaning to iterating over their fields in a statically-typed language. You may be thinking in terms of dynamic languages, which make this easy, because everything there is heterogeneous. But Rust is not like that. And if you really need that, Rust does provide you the tools you need: proc macros. You can write a proc macro to have reflection-like abilities.

But really, you should probably rethink if structs are really the way to go.
